# Proper display of custom QItemDelegates

Tags: combobox, delegates, qtableview, qstandarditemmodel

I am trying to use simple example code I've found in Google.
Everything works except as soon as I set the delegate for the column, it's displaying gets buggy.
Here are the [line](https://github.com/mekkanizer/untitled/blob/60c8b9d8af256ad16a9eafadadaf01b42604a7bb/mainwindow.cpp#L23) where I set the "Bank" string as a value for both rows and [comboboxdelegate.cpp](https://github.com/mekkanizer/untitled/blob/master/comboboxdelegate.cpp)
Here's a screenshot of MainWindow
[image: screenshot]
The question is, if the data is stored in model, why is it not displayed properly? Because if I change the value using combobox, what is displayed in cell still stays as shown in screenshot. However pressing button shows that data in model has been changed

P.S. I am not concerned about editor not being persistently visible, I'm concerned about displayed cell value being something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change the line `QString text = items[index.row()].c_str()` to `index.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString()`.
So while painting the delegate Qt will access data stored in model, not in delegate's option vector
I also had to change `model->setData(index, _editor->currentIndex());` to `model->setData(index, _editor->currentText());`